# Sizing a Common Mode Choke - Inrush or Normal Current

Tags: circuit-design, common-mode-choke

I am looking to use an [LS05-13B05R3](https://www.mornsun-power.com/html/pdf/LS05-13B05R3.html) in a design, and am looking at a choke such as the [RN114-0.3-02-47M](https://www.schaffner.com/fileadmin/user_upload/pim/products/datasheets/RN_series.pdf).  Is this suitable given the lower current requirement of the LS05, or should I size it for the higher inrush current?  It may not be needed as a choke is not mentioned in the datasheet for the LS05, but I put in a varistor and filter caps as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the maximum current that can flow for an extended amount of time. I.e. inrush is irrelevant

Comment: Sorry I just want to be sure, so you're saying the 40A inrush current is irrelevant given normal current consumption is 100mA?  The choke is rated for 300mA, so it should be fine?

Comment: Yes, that's what I say  @Jeff. There is a rare failure case though: the PSU fails and then draws an anomalous input current of 0.5 A. The 1 A fuse won't blow, but the CMC may overheat and fail ungracefully. So if 99.999% safe isn't enough for you, then at least make sure that the the CMC rating accommodates the fuse trip current